# How to make the ul HTML list navigation using Keyboard arrows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

if I have `HTML ul` list, how to allow list navigation using arrows in keyboard ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A working example [keypress navigation with jQuery](http://www.marcofolio.net/webdesign/advanced_keypress_navigation_with_jquery.html)

Comment: That site seems to be down and you didn't post any details.

Answer (score 6):

Give your ul and li, a `tabindex` value so that they are focusable. Once this is done, you can catch key events for the same and handle your navigation accordingly. Or if you have an `<a>` inside each `<li>`, you can skip the `tabindex` part and go straight to handling key events for the `<a>` element.